# What causes an iOS app to be restarted? Trying to persist state

Tags: ios

I have an iOS app that has 2 views:

1. A page that allows you to put in a URL
2. A page that loads the URL and has basic browsing functionality such as back, forward, and refresh.

I want the browser to remember its state in part 2 without having to re-enter the address from step 1.

I have noticed that if I hit the home button and then go back to the app, it will show the web view (if I have put in the address).

But after a little bit of time I try to launch the app, it goes back to the first initial view.

What can I do to retain state so it doesn't go back to the login or is this out of my control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once an app is backgrounded, it's the at the operating system's discretion (i.e. Apple's) to determine how long to keep the app around before the memory is reallocated and the app is terminated. This behavior is to improve performance, reserve battery life, and should not be bypassed except under certain circumstances (like if the app is communicating with a Bluetooth device).

There are several techniques to retain state if the app is closed from the background.

With [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSUserDefaults/standardUserDefaults), your app gets a database that can store strings / numbers / urls / etc that persist across app launches. They can even be synced in the cloud as well to other devices that the users owns.

Caching is another option. Locally storing the retrieved page content that the user loaded might be what you want. In that case, take a look at the [file system programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW2).

If you're trying to do something more complicated, like persist a session. You can configure that by grabbing the returned session cookie on the login callback, or with [NSHTTPCookieStorage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks I will give the NSHTTPCookieStorage a shot.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do what you are proposing would be to store the url in NSUserDefaults. This is a dictionary that persists, but bare in mind that it should only be used for small pieces of data. I realise this may not be the exact solution you are looking for, and if you were wanting to implement more complicated behaviour a database of values that is loaded on app startup would be suitable

Comment: I actually already do this I was just simplify my example. I save the URL in NSUserDefaults and when it re-loads it sends them to the url..but they need to login again as it uses a php session. How does Safari do this?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, iOS will choose to kill your app when it needs to free some memory. You can alleviate this by making your app as lightweight as possible, and by freeing up as much memory as you can when going to the background.

To address your the problem, then, you should make your application save its current state (most likely in the NSUserDefaults, or even in Core Data in some cases) when going to the background, and restoring it when it does get relaunched.

For example, you could save your URL in the `NSUserDefaults` as soon as you reach "step 2" (e.g. in the `-viewDidLoad` of your viewController). When the app gets restarted, you check the user defaults and, if you find the stored URL, you can immediately push the view controller for the "step 2" (this should be done in `-applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in your app delegate).

Some example code:

```
# AppDelegate.m
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    ...
    NSString *url = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"YourAppURL"];
    if (url) {
        // Jump directly to step 2
    } else {
        // Start your normal flow
    }
    ...
}

# ViewControllerStep2.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.url forKey:@"YourAppURL"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    ...
}
```

Of course there could (and probably should) be some extra logic to remove the URL from the defaults when not needed anymore.

As for keeping a potential PHP session active, if you have control over the web service you should make it return a "non-session" cookie (i.e. with a real expiration date in the future) to keep authentication even when the browser (or in your case the app) gets closed.

This way, the cookie handling system automatically takes care of saving and reusing your cookies. This is a sort of "remember me" feature.

If that is not possible, you should manually save and restore the PHPSESSID cookie returned from the server (in a similar way I suggested above for the URL). This would require you to write some code to interact with the [NSHTTPCookieStorage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Bear in mind that when doing this, the server will still garbage collect your session after a certain amount of time, so you may be asked again to log in.